# How to get the url via getInitialUrl() before app was installed?

Tags: react-native

React-Native app.
I have a url (part of a campaign) that send users to install the app from the stores.
Is it possible to get the url (probably with getInitialUrl) that send the user to install the app, from within the app?

If so how?

Example of what I want to do:
Create with a campaign engine the link https://got-get-my-app/SSDHGHCV --> user sent to Play Store --> install it --> I'll parse the url and send the event with data SSDHGHCV to my server.

Answer (score 1):

That is only possible via [dynamic links](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage)
It is a bit tricky to implement and then also to test, but you will probably find your way on SO.

Comment: Thanks - why it is only possible with dynamic links and not with Linking.getInitialURL()?

Comment: Linking allows you to get links from your phone when the app is already installed. To go the route through the appstore you need to somehow link to the store, then install and still get the link into the app and that is what dynamic links are for and it is something that deep links do not cover. As far as I know there is no other way.